# What is the fastest/proper way to see if a FeatureCollection contains no Features

Tags: google-earth-engine

Take this code example, where `mylabel` is a `ui.Label`:

```
var mypt = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.Geometry.Point(Map.getCenter().coordinates()));

var states = ee.FeatureCollection('TIGER/2016/States');

var selectedstate = states.filterBounds(mypt);
var selstatename = selectedstate.first().get('NAME');
selstatename.evaluate(function(result) {
    if (result) {
       mylabel.setValue('State:  ' + result.toString());
    }
});
```

In the above simplified example, if the user has their map centered, say, over the ocean, then selectedstate will be a FeatureCollection with no Features in it.  In that case, I can skip the following `selstatename.first().get('NAME');` and `selstatename.evaluate`

I'm pretty sure there's got to be an easy way to check that, hopefully combined in the `.filterBounds` step so I don't have to send requests to the server twice, if that makes sense?

THIS IS ANSWERED HERE: [How to get several property values at once so there is only one call to .`evaluate`](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/325731/how-to-get-several-property-values-at-once-so-there-is-only-one-call-to-evalua)

Comment: THIS QUESTION IS ANSWERED HERE: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/325731/how-to-get-several-property-values-at-once-so-there-is-only-one-call-to-evalua

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want any excecution to occur when there is no state at the point, you can probably best first evaluate the size of the collection after the `filterBounds()`.

Running `.size()` on the collection return 0 if there was no state. Evaluating that number to the client-side enables to run a client-side IF statement similar as you did for the name of the state:

```
// filter
var selectedstate = states.filterBounds(mypt);
// evaluate to the client side
selectedstate.size().evaluate(function(size) {
  if (size > 0) {
    // evaluate the name to the client side
    var selstatename = selectedstate.first().get('NAME');
    selstatename.evaluate(function(result) {
          mylabel.setValue('State:  ' + result.toString());
    });  
  }
  // just for visualization, add an else statement to show that nothing happens
  else {
    mylabel.setValue('State:  ' + 'There was no TIGER-state');
  }
});
```

[Link code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/f2a012e8abf28c4518f69bc0dc530e68)

Comment: Thank you @Kuik.  I had considered and tried that option, but assuming that a user would most often click in a valid state (vs. the ocean), then that means two separate `.evaluate` calls to the server, right?  I was hoping there would be a way to only use one `.evaluate` call by somehow combining the check in the same call.

Comment: Yes that's also possible, but you asked for combining it in the `filterBounds()` option. Here is an idea how to do it with one `evaluate`: [link code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/cf8a42f27065bfad5f799d4a36c7dd3d). You should then continue with the code you are writing for the case the is a TIGER state within the curly brackets of the first IF-statement

Comment: Thanks @Kuik.  Your code is essentially what I'm currently doing.  I should have better explained the error.  The user doesn't see an error, but if you look in the chrome dev tools at the Console, everytime the user centers the map outside of any state (e.g. over the ocean), this error appears in the console:  "POST https://earthengine.googleapis.com/api/value 400"   I've updated the code sample so that the `mypt` changes every time the center changes (plus a debounce so it doesn't over-fire while dragging):  [LINK CODE](https://code.earthengine.google.com/2c4d2010e86fd4eb2ceff49b009c57ba)

Comment: Continuing above, the Post 400 (Bad request) error seen in the console seems to come from when this line returns a FeatureCollection with no Features: `var selectedstate = states.filterBounds(mypt);`    That is why my thought was to find a way to combine the 'check' for an empty FeatureCollection with the `filterBounds`.

Comment: By the way, my actual layer has over 50,000 polygon features in it with tons of spots where there is no polygon, and so the 400 error fires constantly.