# How to get several property values at once so there is only one call to .`evaluate`

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have a large FeatureCollection (100,000+ polygons) and want to get several values from it at once to display in a `ui.Label` with only one call to `.evaluate`.  I have found the following way to do it that works but want to check if this is the BEST way:

```
var selectedstr = (ee.Feature(selectedstate.first()).select(['NAME', 'GEOID', 'ALAND', 'AWATER'], null, false)).toDictionary().values(['NAME', 'GEOID', 'ALAND', 'AWATER']);
var selectedarray;
selectedstr.evaluate(function(result) {
    if (result) {
      selectedarray = result.toString().split(",");
        mylabel.setValue(selectedarray[0] + ", " + selectedarray[1]  + ", " + selectedarray[2]  + ", " + selectedarray[3]);
        // do other stuff
    }
});
```

[Here's a working example on a much smaller layer.](https://code.earthengine.google.com/c31dae7cdea59a3bfbb78a075b9b7b27)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the right general idea — you should bundle all the results you want into one `ComputedValue` and `evaluate` that. To simplify and improve your code so far, you can delete `.toString().split(",")`. The result is already a JavaScript array so doing this is at best redundant and at worst corrupts the data (e.g. if one of the values is a string containing a comma).

But in the bigger picture: You don't need to convert the properties to a dictionary and then to an array — just **evaluate the feature itself.** (But it is good to still use `.select()`, like you already are, so you don't compute and download any properties or geometry you don't actually plan to use.)

In order to handle the case when the collection is empty without encountering an error, we do `.select()` on the features *before* taking the first feature of the collection. (This will not waste computation because only the features needed for the final result are actually evaluated.)

```
var selectedFeature = selectedstate
  .map(function(feature) {
    return feature.select(['NAME', 'GEOID', 'ALAND', 'AWATER'], null, false);
  })
  .first();
selectedFeature.evaluate(function(evaluatedFeature) {
  if (evaluatedFeature) {
    var properties = evaluatedFeature.properties;
    mylabel.setValue(
      properties.NAME + ", " +
      properties.GEOID + ", " + 
      properties.ALAND + ", " + 
      properties.AWATER);
  } else {
    mylabel.setValue("Nothing selected");
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you @kevin-reid .  Very helpful!

Comment: The only change I'm making is regarding not needing to use `if (result) { ... }` because if the user clicks in a place where a polygon is not present (in the sample code, that would be the ocean outside of any State) then my `else` fires and looks for something in another layer.  Related to this, I posted another question (link in next comment) that pertains to if a user clicks outside the layer, then `selectedFeature` in your code above is a featureless and the chrome console shows a "POST ... 400" error.

Comment: [link referenced in my prior comment] (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/325461/what-is-the-fastest-proper-way-to-see-if-a-featurecollection-contains-no-feature/325466?noredirect=1#comment530467_325466)

Comment: @r_m Ah, I had not considered the nothing-selected case. I've now updated my example code and checked that it does succeed in that case.

Comment: Yes, this runs and shows "Nothing selected" when you click outside of any state, but unfortunately it still shows a "POST ... 400" error. (If you open the console in Chrome, each time you click in the ocean, a 400 error will appear).  Updated link that changes map center each time you click, using your code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/b9a26c4448f93b761f6d727256a4e6bf

Comment: The exact error in the console is: "Failed to load resource: earthengine.googleapis.com/api/value:1    the server responded with a value of 400 ( )"

Comment: @r_m I see! Then this is actually a bug (two bugs): that the callback is being called even though there is an error, and that the detailed error message is not being shown at all. I'll pass that on. The error not being shown is that `select()` can't be called on the null that comes from `.first()`. One fix for this — there are probably other approaches — is to put `.select()` inside a `.map()` to (conceptually, not actually!) apply it to however many elements of the collection exist, before selecting the first one of them. I've confirmed this functions without an error.

Comment: @r_m Oops, I misread the documentation. .evaluate() is doing what it should, but what it's doing is calling the callback with a second argument containing the full error message.

Comment: Any thoughts on how to change the code to capture that second argument so it doesn't become a POST 400 error?

Comment: @r_m I updated my answer with code using `.map()` which will avoid _causing_ the error. The callback second argument is entirely about _reacting_ to errors.

Comment: That did the trick @kevin-reid!  Thanks for all the help

Comment: @r_m You're welcome! Please click the checkmark to accept this answer if you are satisfied and no longer looking for answers to this question (or not, if you still are).